# writing to SSol.txt was successful, but how can i read SSol.txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python 3.6.1. I am self-taught in Python.. I am unable to understand what this error is.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import urllib.request as request    

def a():    
    url=("https://rp5.ru/%EC%95%88%EB%8F%99%EC%9D%98_%EB%82%A0%EC%94%A8,_%EA%B2%BD%EB%B6%81")
    raw_data = request.urlopen(url).read() #Bytes
    text = raw_data.decode("utf-8")
    where = text.find('k;">')
    start_where = where +4
    end_start = where +7
    f = open("SSSol.txt", 'w+')
    decoded = int(text[start_where:end_start])
    k=f.write(str(decoded))
    t = str(f.readline())
    messagebox.showinfo("hello",t)

ttk.Button(win, text="?", command=a).grid()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gwaK.png)

No error occurred, but nothing was output.

Comment: maybe rewind the file `f.seek(0)`. Or close the file and open it again for writing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you're reusing the `f` handle after having written to it.

```
f = open("SSSol.txt", 'w+')
decoded = int(text[start_where:end_start])
k=f.write(str(decoded))
```

that part is OK. Now:

```
t = str(f.readline())
```

you're reading from the end of the file so `t` is an empty string. So either:

- Do `f.seek(0)` first to rewind the file
- close `f` and open it again, this time using `r` mode (read-only). (would be safer anyway)

(that said, I suppose that it's not your real code, as writing + reading the same file in the same method is rather ineffective when you already have the buffer handy)